# Ruby: difference between &= and &&=

Tags: ruby, logical-operators

I have the impression I can use

```
bool &= true
# and
bool &&= true
# indifferently
```

Is there any difference between two? Is one solution unrecommended?

Actually

```
bool = true & false # false
```

So what's the difference between `&` and `&&` in general? (I guess the same applies for `||`)

Comment: I don't know Ruby but  I guess `&=` for bitwise and `&&=` for logical and

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115045/ruby-what-does-the-snippet-num-1-0-exactly-do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
x = 5
x |= 2
=> 7
```

|= and &= are equivalent to the bitwise x = x | 2 and x = x & 2

vs

```
x = 5
x ||= 2
=> 5
```

In the second statement, `x ||= 2`, it means `x = 2` if x is nil, otherwise it's x. 
( `x = (x || 2)`  ; the expression `x || 2` returns x if x is anything but nil otherwise it returns 2.

`x ||= 'foo'` is actually very common in Ruby (set x to foo is x is not already set)

`x = (x & 3)` (which is equivalent to `x &= 3`), returns 3 (the second operand) unless x is 0, it returns 0) 
)

The same logic applies for & but it was easier to find an example on the top of my mind for |

=)

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between the keywords is that the first `|` is a method, and can be redefined for a class, and the second `||` is not, and can be never defined as a method, and just used for language syntax, as you can see in example below:

```
Array.new.respond_to?( :| )
# => true 
Array.new.respond_to?( :|| )
SyntaxError: (irb):35: syntax error, unexpected tOP_ASGN, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
```

So, when you have applied the `#|` method it is able to return a value that differs from `true`, or `false`. Although for *ruby*'s `TrueClass`, and `FalseClass` those values are `true` or `false`, but other descendants could redefine the return value, however, for `Array` and `Set` classes it implements functions similar to boolean bitwise operation. So can be sure that the `true` or `false` class's methods return also `true` or `false`. Otherwise, the keyword `||` is real language boolean operator, however it operates with values *true*, and *not-true*, you can see it on example:

```
'value1' || 'value2'
# => "value1" 
true || false
# => true
'value1' || false
# => "value1" 
false || 'value2'
# => "value2"
```

The return valus is always subordinated to logical expression, but the values of it are, as I denoted above, *true*, and *not-true*. Therefore you see in example return values not only of `true/false` pair, but of the real variable values too, and you can use it as `if` conditional operators as follows:

```
'value1' || 'value2'
```

and

```
if 'value1'
   'value1'
else
   'value2'
end
```

will return the same value.

According the *or-equal* assignment we see the following:

```
A |= false
# NameError: uninitialized constant A
a |= false
# false
A ||= false
# => false
```

In first case we are able to split `|=` operation into the two: call to `#|` method, and to assign the result to the variable. In the second case the ruby interpreter sees the whole operator `||=`, verifies weither it is `nil` or *undefined*, and if yes assign to the variable or to the const the expression result.

The pair `&`, `&&` has the same explanation.

Comment: Not down-voting, seeing the time you spent answering, but methinks at least *mention* that `&` and `|` usually are bitwise operators, and that they're used for other things (which, in effect, are very similar to a bitwise and/or) by classes such as `Array` and `Set`.

Comment: :|| gives you illegal syntax error. You should quote the symbol :'||'.

Comment: @Yossi the `:<<` don't issue the same problem. you can't define a method as `def ||`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are only using the `&` operator on boolean values, then there is no difference to `&&`, but if you want to use it with functions that return a boolean value then there is a difference. Have a look at this code:

```
def side_effect(message="hello")
    puts message
    true
end

#writes "hello" 2 times to the console and then returns false
false & side_effect & side_effect

# just returns false without writing "hello" to the console.
false && side_effect && side_effect
```

Comment: In other words, `&&` is a [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) operator, when `&` is a [strict evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Eager_evaluation) version,  also called eager evaluation or greedy evaluation.